# How to initialise mongoose schema in mongoDb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to to create database and collections for all schema/model files on node.js application startup/mongoose connection to db. (not to seed the database but initialise/set the structure schema on db)

My model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// define the schema
var modelSchema = new Schema({
    appId: {
        type: String,
        indexed: true
    }
});

// export the Model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Model', modelSchema)
```

And i am using this method to connect to DB:

```
mongoose.connect(mongodbUri, mongooseOptions);
```

At the moment mongoose creates the schema in db only when I insert something to the database.

Comment: Yup you were right that was a stupid mistake. I though that indexed option does exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fix `indexed` to be `index` in your schema, that will end up creating your collection so that its index can also be created when you create the model.